# Creating lots of rects with html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am creating a program in javascript that takes a number, converts it to binary, then fills in a series of cells based on whether they correspond to a one or zero in the binary number. I am starting to create the mechanics.

To fill in many cells at once I am using this code:

```
function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("display");
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  draw();
}

function draw() {
  for (var x = 0; x += 25; x < 250) {
    for (var y = 0; y += 25; y < 250) {
      if (y % 2 == 0) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
      } else {
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
      }
      ctx.fillRect(x, y, 25, 25);
    }
  }
}


window.onload = init;
```

This seems to be a very bad way of doing it. It causes some cells not to be filled in, makes the program very slow, and stops it entirely. The only alternative I can think of is hundreds of lines of `ctx.fillRect()`. Is there a better way of filling in many rectangles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have an infinite loop in your code.

Remember, the syntax for `for` loops is:

```
for(variable;condition;variable-change) {
//block of code
}
```

You switched the `condition` and `variable-change` segments, making it be infinite because `x += 25` is not a conditional that can be evaluated to `true` or `false`. Instead, it will always be `true` because you are merely assigning a variable a new value.

Comment: You are right, he/she needs to switch increment and condition in the code. `for (var x = 0; x < 250;x+=25)`

Comment: Many thanks to the technology these days. I put this in Codepen and it detected an infinite loop, helping me spot the error I wouldn't have otherwise noticed.